# Why 'of' in 'inform somebody of something'?

Tags: prepositions

The verb *inform* uses *of* for a second object, as below:

> I will inform Mr. Brown of your arrival.

I don't know why *of* needs to be used here. Could you explain what *of* means?

Comment: "of" in this case means **about** - *I will inform Mr. Brown of/about your arrival.*

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of idiom.  Some English verbs, usually verbs of giving, take a **direct object** and a second object called an *indirect object*.

> I gave *Mr. Brown* **your regards**.

Some verbs, usually verbs of selection or labeling, take a **direct object** and a second object called an *objective complement*.

> We elected **Mr. Brown** *mayor*.

None of these objects requires a preposition.  It's understood that I gave *to* Mr. Brown and we elected him *as* mayor.

The verb *inform* doesn't fall into the classes above, and it requires a prepositional phrase to complete its meaning.  *Of* here means about.